# Android Studio Version 3.0 Emulator Doesn't Work

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator

Since I updated my Android Studio version, the Emulator doesn't work, inside the AVD Manager I configured the Nexus 5X API 27 the last version, obviously I have got installed the SDK Platform API 27 and every SDK Tool is installed, when I run my project it appears an error which is this one:

Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1

And before this error, sometimes I see this:

Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Missing initial data partition file: C:\Users\Nicco.android\avd\Nexus_5X_API_27.avd/userdata.img

I am getting crazy, I also tried to remove the Instant Run in setting but nothing, it's not the problem..
I don't think its the Emulator's RAM, what should I do? I need to fix this

Comment: you are clearly missing the files needed while starting up in .android folder, try to recreate new one again since your files may have moved or deleted.

Comment: @vikaskumar you mean to configure a new Emulator in the AVD Manager? and with the same API?

Comment: yeah, you can try that.

Comment: @vikaskumar I tried with 4 devices adding the API 27 but as soon as I run the emulator, it has got black screen and there's a message on it which says: performing clean boot: datasnapshot doesn't exist. I don't know if its a problem and I can't even interact with the Emulator window, its stuck

Comment: here i found something you can try
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556725/android-emulator-snapshot-error

Comment: @vikaskumar No nothing.. I think to have found the problem.. when the window Emulator stops working, I click it by using the right click and selecting the "qemu-system-i386.exe" it appears the error message saying that the file libwinpthread-1.dll hasn't been found, try to reinstall the program. what should I do to fix it? qemu-system is the Emulator SDK Tool if I am right

Comment: you must have installed HAXM and has enabled the virtualization then it should work as i am also not sure what may be the reason now. WTW you can look here also.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40931254/could-not-launch-emulator-in-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

try to install the emulator version 27.0.5 this version solved a lot of issues