# Flutter --launch hangs now when it used to work. How to delete the device and re-create?

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator

It's worked for a few months, but `flutter emulator --launch My_Device_Name` no longer completes. It just hangs on on a white background with a circular google-esque busy pointer (and no words). Obviously I need to `flutter emulator --delete My_Device_Name` then `My_Device_Name emulator --create --name My_Device_Name` again, but there's no delete sub-command.

How to get past that ?

I'm on MacOS High Sierra, if that's important, with homebrew installed bits and pieces.

Edit: Deleting AVD snapshots doesn't stop this issue coming back, but it does lower the frequency. It could be our app that's killing the emulator, but only one in 30 times.

Comment: This question is not really Flutter specific. Better to check Android questions about how to clear/reset the emulator state/storage. There are enough existing ones.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556725/android-emulator-snapshot-error