# Android AVD stuck on loading page?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

The only warning is:

Emulator: Warning: restoring GLES1 context from snapshot. App may need reloading.

I have tried many times. And my computer's memory is adequate (16GB).
[image]

Comment: I'm just guessing, but have you tried 'Wipe Data' and/or 'Cold Boot Now' from the AVD manager? (You could also try deleting and recreating the virtual device.)

Comment: Look at this link: old but seems legit. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556725/android-emulator-snapshot-error/10557355